# UIBackgroundFetchResult in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios8, push-notification, xcode7

What's the implication of UIBackgroundFetchResult in completionHandler in didReceiveRemoteNotification call? That is - what purpose is UIBackgroundFetchResult being used by the SDK for?

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Specifically, what happen if I return the following, regardless of whether I have fetched new data when I receive a push notification?

```
UIBackgroundFetchResult fetchResults = UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData;
if (completionHandler) {
    completionHandler(fetchResults);
}
```